# Run android emulator without android sdk

Tags: android, ios, xcode

We want to automate an Android/iOS app testing and my company doesn't allow me to install Android SDK or Xcode. Is there a way I can still write automated test cases in appium or any other tool that will have it's own emulator and doesn't force me to install Android SDK or Xcode?

Comment: For iOS you will need Xcode since there is no other simulator/emulator available.

Comment: How about Android, can we have any alternative other than Android?